# Python freezes upon Tkinter destroy() method

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build simple window with buttons in Tkinter. Exit button should act with destroy() or sys.exit, but both option just lead to no response from window and only force close of Python helps. MacOs, Python 3.9

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.attributes('-alpha',1)
        self.attributes('-topmost',True)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.title('Monitor')
        self.set_ui()


    def set_ui(self):
        exit_b=ttk.Button(self,text='Exit',command=self.app_exit)
        exit_b.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def app_exit(self):
        self.destroy()
    

root=App()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me on Windows (if I add `import tkinter as tk`).  The window closes and the app exits.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Ubuntu and Python 3.9. Application exits with no problems.

Comment: Wow, strange. I do use import tinter as tk, just did not copied that. I see button stays in place and after a few seconds pinter transforms into a loading circle and I have to force end python to end this. VS code also see no bugs.

Comment: Are you using the Apple-supplied Python or your own install? Apparently tkinter can have issues on OS X using the Apple supplied version (more info [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/))

Comment: I am using installed from python.org version for macOS and Visual studio code. file have .ipynb extension.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being noob, and not tested earlier, just switched to Mac from Windows. Simply running it for a test from IDE give this results, but when I export script as a python script with .py extension and running it straight with IDLE all works fine. There is definitely some problems with interaction between VS code IDE and Python interpreter for Apple silicon, cause it should not work like this, and its ridiculous to import script and execute it from IDLE every time just to test it as you write.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).